# POSTGRESQL - Convert Multiple Timezones to CST

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have timestamp stored in my table which is stored in String format. I am however trying to create a view which will save them as timezone. I used the following query:

```
SELECT ((timestamp '2015-10-24 16:38:46') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'CST';
```

however i noticed that my data also has CST and IST formats in the table. So my question here is

1. will the time conversion be affected if CST and IST formats are present in the table ?
2. Is there a better way of handling this?

Providing the screenshot of the table values:
[image]

Comment: A demo with actual data might be helpful here.

Comment: I am trying to convert different timezones into one single uniform timezone. I have CST, IST, UTC. It would be ideal to have them as CST.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any solution out there which could give me one single code to handle multiple timezones. I used a simple case when to solve the problem. But this is not scalable as my DB can have new timezone added.

```
CASE 
WHEN right(t2.stream_item_date,3) = 'UTC' THEN to_timestamp(t2.stream_item_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') at time zone 'CST' 
WHEN right(t2.stream_item_date,3) = 'CST' then to_timestamp(t2.stream_item_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') at time zone 'CST'
WHEN right(t2.stream_item_date,3) = 'CDT' then to_timestamp(t2.stream_item_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') at time zone 'CDT' 
END as stream_item_date
```

Feel free to add in.